# Table with dynamic columns

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I googled around but I was not able in finding a solution to my problem

I'm in this scenario: my customers can create their own forms by specifying fields and data fields. Then the created form is shown to users and users can fill the required data

All data are stored in a repository (mongo DB).

Then there is another section of my web application where my customers can see all saved data in a table

So far so good... all works pretty good

Now I need to export all data of a form in an excel or PDF file

I'm using Jasper Report in order to create the reports

The problem is that I don't know how to design the table in the report because i don't know columns name and count

In fact I have this bean as representation of my mongo db "record"

**FormDataModel**

```
@Document(collection = "e_form_data")
public class FormDataModel extends AbstractModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1733975205300782871L;
    private String dataInserimento;
    @Field
    @Indexed(name = "e_form_id_idx")
    private String eFormId;
    @Field
    private Map<String, Object> eFormData;
    //Getter, setter and contructors.. omitted for smaller text
}
```

The AbstractModel is:

**AbstractModel**

```
public abstract class AbstractModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3154415503243809601L;
    @Id
    protected String id;
    @Field
    protected String creatoDa;
    @Field
    protected String modificatoDa;
    @Field
    protected Date dataCreazione;
    @Field
    protected Date dataModifica;
    //Getter, setter and contructors.. omitted for smaller text
}
```

In my FormDataModel the property ***eFormData*** represents the dynamic data created by the user who fills the web form created by another user

This means, basically, that I don't know how this form will be created and which fields it will contain

I just now that Map keys are the columns of my table while Map values are columns values
How can I iterate/use this Map in my report? Any Suggestion?

**EDIT**

As suggested by Petter Friberg I'll try to be more precise
The problem is the following one; let's assume i use a JRBeanCollectionDataSource as datasource and let's assume i use this code to fill and create my report:

```
List<FormDataModel> datiForm = //recover data from mongo repository
reportData.setDatiForm(datiForm);
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
parameters.put("nomeForm", reportData.getFormName());
parameters.put("codiceForm", reportData.getFormCode());
parameters.put("descrizioneForm", reportData.getFormDescription());
InputStream fis = //Get input stream for company logo
parameters.put("logo", fis);
InputStream ris = //Get the input stream of the compiled report (I don't want to recompile report at every HTTP request)
InputStream compiledReport = ris;
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledReport, parameters, new  JRBeanCollectionDataSource(datiForm, true));        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint,"/home/angelo/Scrivania/report/report1.pdf");
```

As yuo can see I take data and some other information from mongo repository and I use the JRBeanCollectionDataSource as report datasource
Now my List of Beans is built with ***FormDataModel*** object; what I want to build in my report is a table where columns names are the keys of the Map eFormData and columns values are the values of this map
The main problem is that I don't know what is contained inside the Map because it is decided by another user, so what i'm looking for is a way to build a table inside my report by cycling the Map; the table inside the report should look like this:

```html
<table>
  <!-- This first row is built by taking the keys in the Map of one element of my datasource -->
  <tr>
    <th>Map Key 1</th>
    <th>Map Key 2</th>
    <th>Map Key 3</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- Form here, each row is built by cycling my datasource and for each element i'll take the Map values to build the several columns of the row -->
  <tr>
    <td>Map Value 1</td>
    <td>Map Value 2</td>
    <td>Map Value 3</td>
  </tr>  
 </table>
```

Now I think I can't have standard names in my jrxml (example col1, col2 etc...) because if i don't know how many columns can be inside the table i should use something like undefined name col1, col2..... col10000 hoping that in the map there will not be present more than 10000 fields (very un common scenario but when people are free to do whatever they want... it can be done)
What would be the best solution for my scenario? I was thinking to use also a scriptlet but i'm not sure in how to use it

I hope I was more clear in specifying where I'm stucked

Moreover: what are  dynamic-jasper? Never heard about them

Comment: This question is too broad and opinion based since there are different solutions, from keeping standard field names in jrxml (remap your datasource) example col1, col2 etc to using a crosstable (not considering that also dynamic-jasper exists). Which is the best solution for you?, well study crosstable some, then try one. If you still have problem [edit] your question to narrow it down and explain where you are stuck.